# Parse platform - how to query based on just a pointer a

Tags: javascript, mongodb, parse-platform

I'm building a commenting system that has a reply feature. the person who creates the parent or primary comment I save their Profile as a pointer which is fetched using this line of code below
`let myProfile: Parse.Object = await parentThread.get('profile').fetch(masterKey)`

the replies are stored in an array struct under this main thread, replies are stored basically the same way (see below structs)

```
parentComment = {
    threadID: string
    uid: string
    fullname: string
    photos: string
    comment: string
    replies: replyComment[]    
}


replyComment = {
    uid: string
    fullname: string
    photos: string
    comment: string
}
```

I can get the top-level profile no problem but any attempt to pull/generate the reply users profiles in the below map are proving very futile
is there an easier way to get access to data once you have the pointer?

The user profile struct itself doesn't contain any pointers, how can I associate the reply comment with a profile?

```
const user = request.user
const req = request.params
if (!req) throw 'request params is required'   
if (!req.eventID) throw 'request event params is required'        
const getEventData: ParseEvent = <ParseEvent>await get(Event, req.eventID)

var query = new Parse.Query(EventComment);
    query.equalTo("parent", getEventData);
    query.descending("createdAt");

    const getComments = await query.find();      
    
    const latestUsers = getComments.map( async parentThread => { 
        
       let myProfile: Parse.Object = await parentThread.get('profile').fetch(masterKey) // fetch relational profile    
       let getReplies = parentThread.get("replies")
       
       const returnUser = {
           threadID: parentThread.toJSON().objectId,
           uid: myProfile.get("uid"),
           fullname: myProfile.get("fullname"),
           photos: myProfile.get("photos")[0] || "",   
           comment: parentThread.get("comment"),
           replies: []
       }
        return Promise.resolve( returnUser )
    })
    // Prepare the final timeline data for  the user and merge all data
    const finalUsers = await Promise.all(latestUsers)
```

End result i want to achieve is to populate the  `replies: []` array in `returnUser` with real live user profile data so that if they change their name or profile photo it will display rather than just pushing the data into an array and storing it there

Comment: What is the data type for `replies` field in your Parse schema?

Comment: Its just a simple array

Comment: Array of what? Pointers, objects, or just string (ids)?